# Test Google Assistant integration for the app from closed beta

Tags: android, android-intent, app-actions

Google provides the tools (App Actions Test Tool and App links assistant) for testing intents using Android Studio at the development stage.

But there is a question: **can I test app integration with Google Assistant at the closed beta stage (before app release at the Google Play): voice commands, receiving intents and etc.?**

For example: at the tests using the App Actions Test Tool and App links assistant deep links and BIIs work fine. Next, I want to test these features at the "real-life case" using Google Assistant and my app from the closed beta. Is this possible?

P.S.: I'm especially interested in ["Open app feature" intent](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature)

Answer (score 0):

Apps published to any distribution channel in the Play store should have usable app actions for the users that are able to download them.  This is something you should be able to test for yourself pretty easily.